# NHibernate Conditional Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, database, nhibernate, orm

I was recently put in charge of a new project for storing our analytics data. I want to give ORM a shot; the mapping doesn't seem difficult but this problem has me vexed.

This database will store data for Google Analytics, Quantcast, and any future analytics provider. I was pretty much given the schema that needs to be used. They want it to be very general which is possible until I store the matrices as we track different ones for each provider.

The table layout is as such:

[image]

tblClient - Stores all the client websites.
tblProfile - 1 or more belong to a client. Stores profile data such as what provider this profile is is using and the profile_type.
tblProvider - Stores data as to whether a profile is a GoogleAnalytics, Quantcast, or other analytics profile.
tblProfile_Type - The type of track for the client site. We have client sites broken down into different sections. That is tracked here.

The problem comes when I need to link the profile table to a metrix table. On this diagram I only have the one for Google but there will be others. I need it to link based on the FK column for Provider_Type in the profile table. Is that possible?

Comment: So you are going to have multiple metrix tables, and which one to join profile to depends on the provider id?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "any" type mapping.

[Any Type Mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-types-anymapping)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have many-to-one relation between tblAny_Profile and tblAny_Provider. 
May be 'invert' this relationship by having one-to-many relationship between 
tblAny_Provider and tblAny_Profile? 
Such way you'll have Bag or List property in tblAny_Provider entity having many instances of tblAny_Profile entities.

Comment: The problem is creating the proper relation to Google_Metric_Set or Quantcast_Metric_Set(not showed in diagram) based on the type of profile.